# Prevent printing spaces in C# TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to make a TextBox that doesn't allow entering spaces. I disabled typing spaces with the keyboard:

```
void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    } 
}
```

But if the user copies a string with spaces like "Hello world", he can paste it into the TextBox and there will be spaces in it.

Answer (score 3):

you can add a `TextChanged` Event Handler for your `TextBox` and add below code in that TextChanged event:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: It resets the TextBox pointer to the start when the user enter spaces.

Answer (score 2):

A better control approach

```
 private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) {                
            removeSpaces();
        }
        //Handle Ctrl+Ins
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert)
        {
            removeSpaces();
        } 
    }

private void removeSpaces()
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }
```

// To control Mouse Right click

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                textBox1.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            }
        }
```

SIMPLE Solution for all

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: Ctrl+Ins will still work, as well as pasting with a mouse

Comment: Updated answer,two approaches, hope one of them suitable for your needs. Thanks

Comment: The third solution resets the TextBox pointer to the start when the user enter spaces.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is removing white space after entering data. Like:

```
txt_Box.Text = txt_Box.Text.Replace(" ","");
```

Comment: It resets the TextBox pointer to the start when the user enter spaces.